# Index identified when using Angular Drag and Drop CDK is incorrect, causing misaligned order in array

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angulardraganddroplists

**The Environment**

I have an Angular 15.2 app that is designed to build a 'photoshop-like' experience using the HTML Canvas.

I am attempting to use the Material Design Drag and Drop CDK found [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) to reorder element in an array which eventually I will use to control the layer order within the canvas.

As you can see from the HTML, I have a custom angular component that within contains the layout for one of the layers/blocks in the vertical list that you'll see further down in screenshots.

I have 4 items in an array, that is iterated over using `*ngFor`.

**The Code**

Here is the **HTML** for this:

```
<div class="layer-list" cdkDropList
        cdkDragPreviewContainer="parent" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div *ngFor="let layer of layerList" class="layer cdkdrag-box" cdkDrag>
                <app-existing-element-block class="individual-layer" [dataId]="layer.dataId" cdkDragBoundary=".layer-list"
                    [title]="layer.title" [type]="layer.type" [icon]="layer.icon"
                    (elementVisibilityChanged)="toggleElementVisibility($event)" (elementDeleted)="deleteElement($event)">
                </app-existing-element-block>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the **TS** for controlling the detection of change in the drag/drop functionality:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousIndex !== event.currentIndex) {
        const layersCopy = Array.from(this.layerList);
        console.log('event previous index:', +' ' + event.previousIndex);
        console.log('event current index:', +' ' + event.currentIndex);
        moveItemInArray(layersCopy, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        this.layerListService.updateLayers(layersCopy);
        this.getUpdatedLayerList();
    }
}
```

In the layer service, I have this:

```
updateLayers(layers: LayerElement[]) {
    this.layers = [...layers];
}
```

and the 'get updated layer list' does this:

```
getLayers(): LayerElement[] {
    return [...this.layers];
}
```

**The Problem**

When dropping item at index 0, to replace item at index 1, 2 or 3, Angular's Drag and drop CDK is reporting incorrect index numbers as to where it thinks the item is dropped.

For example, if I pick up item at index 0, and drop it over the top/in place of item at index 1, I get the following logs:

**Before the ordering:** 
[image: First Screenshot Before]

**Console Log:** 
[image: First Log]

**After ordering:** 
[image: First Screenshot After]

The previous index is 1 where it should be 0, and the new/current index it thinks I'm trying to drop it at, is **2 higher** than where it should be. It should be 1. As you can see, this also throws the ordering out completely.

Here's what we get if I drop the item at index 0, to index 2:

**Before the ordering:** 
[image: Second Screenshot Before]

**Console log:** 
[image: Second Log]

**After ordering:** 
[image: Second Screenshot After]

As you can see, the index it thinks I'm trying to drop it at, is **4 higher** than where it should be.

Further to this, the array of items therefore updates with the incorrect values, and reorders the items accordingly with the new order as you've seen in the above screenshots.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just sharing here my findings that were possible only because your example.
I had a similar problem on Angular 12 and your example helped me to build a PoC to test possible solutions.
One solution that worked using your example is update Angular to 16th. This issue seems to be fixed in the latests versions.
In my case, I noticed that when the drag item is a complex form the indexes stop working, but an update to the Angular version was not viable, so, I've built an Array mapping the correct indexes to the wrong DragNDrop CDK indexes, and it worked.